# Determining grade distribution by class

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, window-functions, percentage

I have a table which tracks the students performance in the courses.

| facultyID | academicYear | courseID | studentID | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | 1 | 2 | A |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | 1 | 3 | A |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | 1 | 4 | B |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | 1 | 5 | B |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | 1 | 6 | C |

The first three columns forms a 'class', while the grade column can assume the following values (A, B, C, D and E).

I'm trying to build a query that counts how many times each grade value has occurred in each class, and the proportion of that grade value to the overall grade for that class.

The result will be:

| facultyID | academicYear | courseID | grade | gradeCount | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | 1 | A | 3 | 50 |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | 1 | B | 2 | 33.333 |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | 1 | C | 1 | 16.667 |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | 1 | D | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | 1 | E | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Looks like this needs some aggregation, have you already tried any code to solve it?

Comment: Yes, but I think it was complicated query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `CROSS` join of all distinct *classes* to all distinct *grades* and a `LEFT` join to the table to aggregate:

```
WITH 
  classes AS (SELECT DISTINCT facultyID, academicYear, courseID FROM tablename),
  grades AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E')) AS g(grade))
SELECT c.facultyID, c.academicYear, c.courseID, g.grade,
       COUNT(t.grade) AS gradeCount,
       ROUND(100.0 * COUNT(t.grade) / SUM(COUNT(t.grade)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.facultyID, c.academicYear, c.courseID), 3) AS percentage
FROM classes c CROSS JOIN grades g
LEFT JOIN tablename t 
ON t.facultyID = c.facultyID AND t.academicYear = c.academicYear AND t.courseID = c.courseID AND t.grade = g.grade
GROUP BY c.facultyID, c.academicYear, c.courseID, g.grade
ORDER BY c.facultyID, c.academicYear, c.courseID, g.grade;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/f7k4L49I).